# How to change the tooltip of browser url to custom message

Tags: angular5, tooltip

When I hover over the browser URL section, I need to set custom tool-tip instead of the same URL in the tool-tip.
For Example :
My browser URL is containing "www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1" if I hover over the url it should have some message about the page like "Stack Overflow"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML attribute ***title***

```
<a title="Stack Overflow" href="www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1">Question 1</a>
```

Comment: I am not hardcoding the URL anywhere in my angular app. If I hit the url say www.stackoverflow.com, I need to know the place in angular where I can inject that tooltip section.

Comment: Do you mean a tooltip component?